# echo html tags in status

Tags: php, html, facebook

I am updating facebook status with my feed update from my site,
and facebook status followed by link of feed.

I'm using

```
echo $_POST['msg']."  @"."<a href='http://xxx.ch/comment.php?id=".$result."'>link</a>";
```

but the status updates in facebook is like that,

```
msg @<a href='http://xxx.ch/comment.php?id=2>link</a>
```

I want only

```
msg @ link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't support html tags in messages. Just specify url and it will be shown as url.

Answer (score 0):

Links should be posted in `link` parameter, you can also select custom name for that one. Don't use `message` for this purpose

Comment: sorry but i don't know how to use link parameter for posting in facebook. can you give me example?

Comment: @Kartik: I assume you use "message" parameter in POST. Append &link=yourlinkhere and that's it. Read [doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Answer (score 0):

i got it using tinyurl:

```
function get_tiny_url($url)  {
$ch = curl_init();  
  $timeout = 5;  
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url='.$url);  
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);  
  $data = curl_exec($ch);  
  curl_close($ch);  
  return $data;  
}
$new_url = get_tiny_url('http://xxx.ch/comment.php?id='.$result);
    echo $_POST['msg']." @  ".$new_url;
```